# Play test : cannot connect to database

Tags: integration-testing, playframework-2.2

I tried to make my test connect to my local PostgreSQL: play test

```
@Before
public void startApp() throws Exception {
    // Set up connection to test database, different from main database. Config better
    // should be used instead of hard-coding.
    Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    settings.put("db.default.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    settings.put("db.default.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name");
    settings.put("db.default.user", "admin");
    settings.put("db.default.password", "pw");
//  settings.put("applyEvolutions.default", "true");
//  settings.put("applyDownEvolutions.default", "true");
//  settings.put("evolutionplugin", "disabled");
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication(settings);
    Helpers.start(app);
}
//
//    @After
//    public void stopApp() throws Exception {
//        Helpers.stop(app);
//    }
//


@Test
public void test() {
    running(testServer(3333, app), HTMLUNIT,
            new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
                public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
                    browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
                    browser.takeScreenShot();
                    assertThat(browser.pageSource()).contains("Login");
                }
            });
}
```

But :

```
[error] Test test.IntegrationTest.test failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Configuration     error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
[error]     at play.api.test.TestServer.start(Selenium.scala:146)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.start(Helpers.java:401)
[error]     at play.test.Helpers.running(Helpers.java:430)
[error]     at test.IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:46)
[error]     ...
[error] Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

My db is on (play run works)

My conf in the hashmap is same as in the application.conf

Any idea ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you copy the same code ? The code say database name is db_name whereas error stack says default.

Comment: I edited my conf just to post but I try with the right one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **no @Before** and **no modification to application.conf** (dev database), this is working

```
@Test
public void test() {
    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Logger.debug("running");
        }
    });
}


@Test
public void testInServer() {
    running(testServer(3333), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            assertThat(
                    WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get().get().getStatus()
            ).isEqualTo(OK);
        }
    });
}


@Test
public void runInBrowser() {
    running(testServer(3333), HTMLUNIT, new F.Callback<TestBrowser>() {
        public void invoke(TestBrowser browser) {
//                browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333");
//                browser.$("a").click();
        }
    });
}
```

Dont forget to add to your appDependencies :

```
      "org.fluentlenium" % "fluentlenium-core" % "0.9.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the original code is that it says `Helpers.start(app);`, but it then passes the `app` variable to  `testServer(3333, app)`. Creating a test server will start up a completely new, separate app (see scala source code for `TestApplication` in `/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/system/ApplicationProvider.scala`).
So `Helpers.start(app)` is not actually starting the app that will be used.

If you need to do any application-specific initialization that will persist through the `testServer` call, instead of using a `@Before` annotation, you need to write a class that derives from `GlobalSettings`, override the `onStart` method, and then create your app with

```
FakeApplication app = fakeApplication(extraConfiguration, new TestGlobalSettings());
```

It is not entirely obvious to me why there would be no connection to the DB in this case, but this is what solved my problem when I wanted to run with an in-memory DB and initialize it for the test server run.